# How can find the substrings that are in alphabetical order within a sorted string list? Python

Tags: python, python-3.x

I should create a program that will find the characters that are in alphabetical order in a given input and find how many characters are in that particular substring or substrings.

For example
Input: cabin
Output: abc, 3

Input: sightfulness
Output: ghi, 3
OUtput: stu, 3

Here is what I have coded so far. I am stuck in the part of checking whether the two consecutive letters in my sorted list is in alphabetical order.

I have converted that string input to a list of characters and removed the duplicates. I already sorted the updated list so far.

```
import string

a = input("Input A: ")

#sorted_a is the sorted letters of the string input a
sorted_a = sorted(a)
print(sorted_a)

#to remove the duplicate letters in sorted_a
#make a temporary list to contain the filtered elements
temp = []
for x in sorted_a:
    if x not in temp:
        temp.append(x)

#pass the temp list to sorted_a, sorted_a list updated
sorted_a = temp
joined_a = "".join(sorted_a)
print(sorted_a)


alphabet = list(string.ascii_letters)
print(alphabet)

def check_list_order(sorted_a):
    in_order_list = []
    for i in sorted_a:
        if any((match := substring) in i for substring in alphabet):
            print(match)

            #this should be the part
            #that i would compare the element
            #in sorted_a with the elements in alphabet
            #to know the order of both of them
            #and to put them ordered characters
            #to in_order_list
            
            if ord(i)+1 == ord(i)+1:
                in_order_list.append(i)
    return in_order_list

print(check_list_order(sorted_a))
```

Answer (score 0):

You could try something like this:

```py
string = input("Input string: ")
chars = sorted(set(string.strip().casefold()))
parts, part = [], ""
for a, b in zip(chars, chars[1:] + ["-"]):
    part += a
    if ord(a) + 1 != ord(b):
        if len(part) > 1:
            parts.append(part)
        part = ""

print(parts)
```

The result `parts` for the input-string `"sightfulness"` would be

```py
['efghi', 'stu']
```

so I'm not quite sure why your output differs: Is there a requirement that you haven't mentioned?

If `-` could be part of the string then replace `... + ["-"]` with something more suitable. If you want to exclude any characters that are not in the alphabet then you could do:

```py
from string import ascii_lowercase as alphabet

string = input("Input string: ")
chars = sorted(set(string.strip().casefold()).intersection(alphabet))
...
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. Your reply helped me so much. And yes, I have given you an incorrect output. Sorry my bad. My code was already done bro. Thanks!